# Las etiquetas necesarias en un documento HTML5

Tags: html, html5, web

Normalmente uso una serie de etiquetas que creo que son las más utilizadas y las más eficientes dentro de la etiqueta .

Me gustaría saber si estoy obviando alguna etiqueta importante, o si estoy utilizando otras que ya no son necesarias para un buen fichero html.

```
<html lang = "idioma">
<title>El título de la página</title>
<meta name="description" content="Descripción de la página" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Palabras clave" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta name=”author” content=”El creador”>
<meta name="owner" content="El propietario" />
<meta name="copyright" content="El propietario" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="period">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es/en..." href="Web en idioma correspondiente">
<link rel="canonical" href="">
<link rel="icon" href="icono" />
<meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="..." />
```

y ya después pondría todas las etiquetas que enlazan con los estilos y los scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Meta tag Keywords:** Google no usa el meta tag Keywords, desde el 2009 la versión oficial de Google sobre el meta tag keywords es que ni lo mira, no lo utiliza y no tiene ningun efecto en el posicionamiento. Se ha usado tanto para hacer spam que han decidido ignorarla. **¿cómo le digo a Google cuales con mis keywords?** Pues poniendo las keywords donde Google cree que deben ir las palabras clave de un artículo. Puedes ver este artículo con muchos consejos útiles: [aquí](https://www.tecnicaseo.com/tecnicas/60-tips-seo-keywords).

**Cómo saber si alguna de las etiquetas meta esta obsoleta?:** te puedes descargar un complemento para tu navegador llamado **Html Validator**, el cual te puede ayudar ver cual esta obsoleta o no, por ejemplo si estas usando un meta para definir un lenguaje por defecto el te pudiese arrojar un error como este:

```
error: Using the “meta” element to specify the document-wide default
language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root
element instead.

At line 6, column 9: <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
```

En HTML5, puede definir **lang** para cada elemento. Eso significa que si tiene un div que contiene chino mandarín, simplemente defina un atributo **lang = "zh-CN"** para ese **div**, como `<div lang = "zh-CN">`.

El complemento esta para [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/html-validator/) y [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/mpbelhhnfhfjnaehkcnnaknldmnocglk).